# RST: How to have an item of a numbered list show itself as multiple lines

Tags: restructuredtext

I want the following visual format:

```
1. Install Miniconda for Python 3.6 from https://conda.io/miniconda.html
2. Open a command prompt
3. Type *conda install numpy*
4. Type *conda install pyopengl*
5. Type *python -m pip install simpylc*
6. Install freeglut as explained on http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/index.php#download
   Alternatively, type:
   *sudo apt-get update*
   *sudo apt-get install build-essential*
   *sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev*
7. Yet another item
8. And yet another
```

How can I achieve that with RST without introducing double line spacing to all "normal" list items?

Comment: This is a 2-year old issue that could use some love in the form of a PR https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/2258

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [rst2html5](https://pypi.org/project/rst2html5/) instead of docutils.

Your list:

```
1. Install Miniconda for Python 3.6 from https://conda.io/miniconda.html
2. Open a command prompt
3. Type :code:`conda install numpy`
4. Type :code:`conda install pyopengl`
5. Type :code:`python -m pip install simpylc`
6. Install freeglut as explained on http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/index.php#download Alternatively, type::

       sudo apt-get update
       sudo apt-get install build-essential
       sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev

7. Yet another item
8. And yet another
```

And the result will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <ol type="1">
        <li>Install Miniconda for Python 3.6 from <a href="https://conda.io/miniconda.html">https://conda.io/miniconda.html</a></li>
        <li>Open a command prompt</li>
        <li>Type <code class="code">conda install numpy</code></li>
        <li>Type <code class="code">conda install pyopengl</code></li>
        <li>Type <code class="code">python -m pip install simpylc</code></li>
        <li>Install freeglut as explained on <a href="http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/index.php#download">http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/index.php#download</a> Alternatively, type:
            <pre>sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev</pre>
        </li>
        <li>Yet another item</li>
        <li>And yet another</li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```